# Python CSV Data Transformation Issue: Applying Conditional Transformations Based on Previous and Next Values

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python script that processes CSV data. The script's purpose is to apply transformations to the numbers in the CSV based on conditions. Specifically, if a number is in the range of 1-4, I want to apply a transformation to both the number before it and the number after it. If the current number is 8-10, I want to decrease it by 2, and if it's in the range 5-7, I want to decrease it by 1.

For example, if the input is:
8,1,8
I want the output to be:
6,1,6
However, my current code only applies these transformations based on the previous number, and I need to apply them to both the previous and next numbers.

I've provided my code below:

```
import csv

# Read the input CSV data
input_filename = 'updated_zeros.csv'
output_filename = 'updated_zeros.csv'

with open(input_filename, mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    rows = list(csv_reader)

# Apply transformations to the data
for row in rows:
    for i in range(1, len(row)):
        current_value = row[i]
        previous_value = row[i - 1]

        if current_value and previous_value:
            current_value = int(current_value)
            previous_value = int(previous_value)

            if 1 <= previous_value <= 4:
                if 8 <= current_value <= 10:
                    row[i] = str(current_value - 2)
                elif 5 <= current_value <= 7:
                    row[i] = str(current_value - 1)

# Write the transformed data to the output CSV file
with open(output_filename, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerows(rows)

# Print the numbers in the "updated_zeros2" file
with open("updated_zeros.csv", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        numbers = line.strip().split(',')
        for number in numbers:
            print(number, end=' ')
        print()  # Newline after each line


print(f'Transformed data saved to {output_filename}')
```

Iterating Over Rows and Values
Value Conversion

Comment: can you provide the structure of the CSV file or the CSV file itself? helps while testing out your code, I am a little unclear about the question as well. can you give more examples and try explaining it a little more?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: this is the content of the .csv 7,3,5,7,8,6,6,7
2,0,6,2,4,6,3
1,3,2,5,1,6,6,8
3,5 what i wanted to do is if i had 8,2,8    i wanted the output to be 6,2,6 but with the code i provided i only got 8,2,6 for some reason it would not change the number before only after so i duplicated the CSV, reversed the rows in one copy, performed the calculations on both copies, then reversed the modified copy back and merged the results, selecting the lower score for each value position.